# Create DateTime in specific time zone then convert to utc

Tags: c#, .net-core

I need to create a DateTime with a set date and time which will be in a specific time zone(West Asia Standard Time, W. Europe Standard Time etc).

DST must be preserved, so offset is out because for half of the year for a given time zone it will be for example +2h and for the other half +3h.

Then I want to convert the date to UTC.

I tried to do it in such a way that I could add this timezone offset later. However, firstly I do not like this solution and I am afraid that I will lose one hour when the time changes twice a year, and secondly I get an error:

> "The UTC Offset for Utc DateTime instances must be 0."

```
var testTime = new DateTime(testDate.Year, testDate.Month, testDate.Day, 4, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("West Asia Standard Time");
var timezoneTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(runTime, timeZoneInfo);
var offset = timeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(timezoneTime);
```

I would like to get this kind of code

```
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("West Asia Standard Time");
var testTime = new DateTime(testDate.Year, testDate.Month, testDate.Day, 4, 0, 0, timeZoneInfo);
var utcTime = testTime.ToUniversalTime();
```

So, to sum up, I want to have method, where I pass year, month, day, hour, minute and timeZone and in return I will get DateTime that is in UTC
In javascript there are libraries, where the given time zone is given as a parameter but I have to do it on the server side.

Comment: `The timezone can be different for each request and DST must be preserved, so offset is out.` I don't understand this statement. Please explain in more detail why offset is out. When you say `offset` what do you _mean_ exactly? Do you mean the `DateTimeOffset` type (which, frankly, is almost certainly certainly what you should be using)? Or something else?

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Be really clear what the input is **and what exact output you want**. Your description of the problem is unclear what outcome you want and what _steps you are taking_ to try and get that outcome. What we really want to know is what _exact_ output you want - just in case you are attacking the problem the wrong way.

Comment: I want to have method, where I pass year, month, day, hour, minute and timeZone and in return I will get DateTime that is in UTC.

A fixed offset is not suitable, because for half of the year for a given time zone it will be +2h and for the other half +3h.

Comment: Put it in your question. Actual code with actual values and specify the **exact** output you want. Preferably a couple of examples, on either side of the DST boundary.

Comment: Also, have you tried `DateTimeOffset` or `NodaTime`? Did they work?

Comment: I've tried DateTimeOffset. I have not checked NodaTime, I will check it. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd basically need [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimetoutc?view=net-5.0) method.

Just make sure the `Kind` property of the passed `DateTime` is `Unspecified`, otherwise the method has special expectations for the `sourceTimeZone` argument and will throw exception.

e.g.

```
var testTime = new DateTime(testDate.Year, testDate.Month, testDate.Day, 4, 0, 0);
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("West Asia Standard Time");
var utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(testTime, timeZoneInfo);;
```